# How to find coefficient of variation (CV) in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 pyspark dataframe i want to find coefficient of variation of that two dataframe.

dataframe1 :

```
          hours    total

           00     75969.0
           01     75302.0
           02     74636.0
           03     73969.0
           04     73302.0
           05     72635.0
```

dataframe2 :-

```
            hours   total1

             00      71535
             01      71182
             02      77628
             03      75984
             04      75276
             05      67259
```

And i want output like these :-

dataframe3 :-

```
      hours       total        total1   CV
       00        75969.0        71535   3.006020
       01        75302.0        71182   2.812594
       02        74636.0        77628   1.965008
       03        73969.0        75984   1.343754
       04        73302.0        75276   1.328595
       05        72635.0        67259   3.842910
```

I have done these by converting pyspark-dataframe to pandas dataframe but i want to calculate CV without going to pandas.
I have done like these

```
     pd1=dataframe1.toPandas()
     pd2=dataframe2.toPandas()
     a4=[]
     list1=[]
     count=len(pd1)  
     print(count)
     import numpy as np
     for i in range(count):
         del a4[:]
         p9=(pd1.total[i])
         p10=(pd2.total1[i])
         a4.append(p10)
         a4.append(p9)
         standard_d1=np.std(a4,ddof=0)
         mean1=np.mean(a4)
         cv=(standard_d1/mean1)*100
         list1.append(cv)
     pd1['cv']=list1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this:

1. Use `window`
2. Use `udf`
3. Use `window` + `udf`

   - First, let's build the DataFrame:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import mean, pandas_udf, PandasUDFType


a1 = [(0, 75969.0), (1, 75302.0), (2, 74636.0), (3, 73969.0), (4, 73302.0), (5, 72635.0)]
a2 = [(0, 71535.0), (1, 71182.0), (2, 77628.0), (3, 75984.0), (4, 75276.0), (5, 67259.0)]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(a1, ['hours', 'total'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(a2, ['hours', 'total'])
df = df1.union(df2)
df.show()

+-----+-------+
|hours|  total|
+-----+-------+
|    0|75969.0|
|    1|75302.0|
|    2|74636.0|
|    3|73969.0|
|    4|73302.0|
|    5|72635.0|
|    0|71535.0|
|    1|71182.0|
|    2|77628.0|
|    3|75984.0|
|    4|75276.0|
|    5|67259.0|
+-----+-------+
```

- Using `udf` only

```
@pandas_udf(FloatType(), PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
def _udf(v):
    return 100.0*np.std(v, ddof=0)/np.mean(v)

df = df.groupBy('hours').agg(_udf(df['total']).alias('CV')).orderBy('hours')
df.show()
```

- Use `window`

```
w = Window.partitionBy('hours')
df = df.withColumn('std', F.stddev_pop('total').over(w))
df = df.withColumn('mean', F.mean('total').over(w))
df = df.withColumn('CV', 100.0*df['std']/df['mean']).dropDuplicates(['hours']).drop(*['total', 'std', 'mean']).orderBy('hours')
df.show()
```

- Use `window` + `udf`

```
w = Window.partitionBy('hours')
df = df.withColumn('CV',_udf('total').over(w)).dropDuplicates(['hours']).orderBy('hours')
df.show()
```

All the above methods give you the results:

```
+-----+---------+
|hours|       CV|
+-----+---------+
|    0|  3.00602|
|    1| 2.812594|
|    2|1.9650081|
|    3|1.3437544|
|    4| 1.328595|
|    5|3.8429096|
+-----+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time but its computation time is more..@niuer

Answer (score 0):

Here since you have only two elements, we have the property that `standard_dev = |total - total1| / 2`. Since `mean = (total + total1) / 2`, we have `CV = 100 * |total - total1| / (total + total1)`.

Therefore :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = dataframe1.join(dataframe2, 'hours', 'inner')
df_final = df.withColumn('CV', F.lit(100) * F.abs(df['total'] - df['total1']) / (df['total'] + df['total1']))
```